# JS loaded PHP file aware of being loaded

Tags: javascript, php

I have a JS file that loads a PHP file inside a PHP website, like this:

> index.php with a `<div>` class “load”.
>
> main.js - load() - test.php inside “load” div in index.php

Now I want users to access the file only via index.php but cannot open the file separately.

I tried global variable in index.php and accessing it in test.php - does not work.

Also I tried server base URI - still won’t work (it’s always the filename)

Any ideas?

Comment: JavaScript only works in the browser (client-side script) and PHP only works on the server (server-side script). If you want you JavaScript to call your php page then you will need to use AJAX.

Comment: I know, but that’s not what I want - I load the file directly inside the index.php. It’s like an include() but with JS. So I can load and unload files.

Comment: The question is - how can the test.php be aware that it’s being loaded onto/inside index.php

Comment: You can do like with forms or Csrf Token. Generate a key while loading index.php and send that key with your ajax request from your js file

Comment: That seems a bit too complicated in my opinion

Comment: PHP files that you do NOT want to be called directly from the browser are placed OUTSIDE of the document root

Comment: That’s not what I want actually. I want the file to be accessible ONLY through the index, but not separately. Imagine it like a web app, which loads only the content. But the content ONLY (server/test.php) should redirect you to index - since it was not LOADED through JS and index isn’t present. Get it?